# How to convert word2vec to glove format

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I did some research and found that gensim has a script to convert glove to word2vec [GLove2Wrod2Vec](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/scripts/glove2word2vec.py). I am looking to do the opposite.

Is there any simple way to convert using gensim or any other library

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between the glove vector file format and the word2vec file format is one line at the beginning of the `.txt` of the word2vec format which has

`<num words> <num dimensions>`

Otherwise the vectors are represented in the same manner. We do not need to change the vectors to change the format.

Quoting the page you linked in the question:

```
Both files are
presented in text format and almost identical except that word2vec includes
number of vectors and its dimension which is only difference regard to GloVe.
Notes
-----
GloVe format (real example can be founded `on Stanford size <https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/>`_) ::
    word1 0.123 0.134 0.532 0.152
    word2 0.934 0.412 0.532 0.159
    word3 0.334 0.241 0.324 0.188
    ...
    word9 0.334 0.241 0.324 0.188
Word2Vec format (real example can be founded `on w2v old repository <https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/>`_) ::
    9 4
    word1 0.123 0.134 0.532 0.152
    word2 0.934 0.412 0.532 0.159
    word3 0.334 0.241 0.324 0.188
    ...
    word9 0.334 0.241 0.324 0.188
```

In the above example, word2vec's first line `9 4` tells us that we have 9 words in the vocabulary which have 4 dimensions each.

**TL;DR**
So, to convert from `w2v` -> `glove` : remove the `<num words> <num dimensions>` line from `w2v`. You can infer it from the file anyway.

To convert from `glove` -> `w2v` : add the `<num words> <num dimensions>` line to `glove`.

You can do it manually but gensim provides a way of going from one to the other.